# How to open the default calendar when clicking on an event in the Gnome Notification Area?

Tags: notification, calendar, gnome-shell

I have a google calendar notification of an event in the gnome-shell notification area, as shown below.  I have set my default calendar application.

When I click on the event notification, noting happens.  I would like the default calendar application to open up, showing the event.

UPDATE:

To test Khurshid Alam's suggestion, I installed ubuntu-gnome 17.04 in a virtual machine. I installed evolution (since it is not installed by default in ubuntu-gnome). I ensured that evolution was set as the default calendar app in /etc/gnome/defaults.list ("text/calendar=evolution.desktop").

I then added my my gmail account to gnome-online accounts.  The gmail account was recognized by evolution, so I did not have to do any separate setup in evolution. After launching evolution, I could see my e-mails and calendar events in evolution.  I created a calendar entry and setup a reminder.  A few minutes before the event, I received a notification in the gnome notification area, as expected.

However, when I clicked on the notification, the evolution calendars view did *not* open.  (Note: evolution did produce its own notifications, but ~only~ if it was running; clicking on ~those~ notifications ~did~ open up the evolution calendar view.  This basically results in two notifications for the same event: one from gnome-online-accounts and one from evolution, ~if~ it is running.).

My experience is that gnome notification area simply does not integrate with ~any~ calendar application at all. All it integrates with is gnome-online accounts to show a notification.  Clicking on the notification does not take you to details about the event; all you can really do is click on the little "x" to dismiss the notification.

Is this correct, or am I missing something?

(END UPDATE)

I have currently selected "Wavebox" as my calendar application, but I had the same issue when I selected "Calendar" (gnome-calendar) as the default calendar application.  I should add that clicking on an e-mail notification in Gnome Shell's notification area *does* open up the default e-mail application (also Wavwebox, in my case).

I am using ubuntu-gnome 17.04.  I do not have evolution installed on my system.

Here is the event notification.  I can hover over the event to  highlight it, but clicking on it does nothing...
[image: Gnome-Shell Notification Area]

Here is the default calendar setting...
[image: Default Calendar Setting]

Comment: Instsll evolution. `sudo apt-get install evolution`. And set default application to either gnome-calendar or evolution.

Comment: So there is no way to set a ~different~ calendar application (other than gnome calendar or evolution) to open?